# Elastic Beanstalk and Symfony bin/console commands

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run the command `doctrine:schema:update`after my deployment. So I prepared this file under `.ebextensions`

`83_post_setup.config`

```
 container_commands:
  01_update_symfony_db:
    command: php /var/app/current/bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

but I keep getting the following error:

`ERROR: [Instance: i-0ffc989ebd7c41d79] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Could not open input file: /var/app/current/bin/console.
container_command 01_update_symfony_db in .ebextensions/83_post_setup.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1]`

I also tried replacing `container_commands:` with `commands:` but then I got ENV problems `ENV RDS_USERNAME not found`, because it was too early to run this command. Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by simply removing the complete path:

```
 01_update_symfony_db:
    command: php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```